# Why can't anonymous users vote more than once from different browsers/machines?

Tags: 8, polls

I created a poll in a Drupal 8 site and I enabled anonymous voting too, but when opening the pool in different browsers/machines, the poll results appear and anonymous users cannot vote.

Please tell me where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that was the issue because of same IP address. But in case of  local network with hundreds of machines, how will that be taken care of, is still a question.
Right resource: [Does poll not allow multiple anonymous votes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13157/does-poll-not-allow-multiple-anonymous-votes?rq=1)